# Changing a page from DropDownList using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple jQuery script that selects the current page from a static dropdownlist, and when the selection changes the script also modifies the href attribute of an anchor tag to reflect the navigation change. Here is my code:

```
<select name="PageSelectDropDown" id="PageSelectDropDown"> 
    <option value="Insulation">Insulation</option> 
    <option value="Windows">Windows</option> 
    <option value="Siding">Siding</option> 
    <option value="Roofing">Roofing</option> 
    <option value="Gutters">Gutters &amp; Gutter Protection</option> 
    <option value="PatioDoors">Patio Doors</option>
</select> 
<a href="" id="clicker">Go!</a> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    //get the current page
    var cPage = '<%= ViewData["CurrentPage"] %>';

    //select the current page from the list
    $("#PageSelectDropDown > option").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val().toLowerCase() == cPage.toLowerCase()) {
            $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
        }
    });

    //change the link target
    $("#PageSelectDropDown").change(function () {
        var str = "";
        $("#PageSelectDropDown option:selected").each(function () {
            str += $(this).val() + " ";
        });
        $("#clicker").attr("href", "/Product/" + str.trim());
        if (cPage != str.trim()) {
            $("#clicker").click();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The only improvement I would like to see on this is for page to automatically change ('auto-click' anchor tag) when the user selects a different page from the dropdownlist.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the problem you are seeing and why not just use location.href?

Comment: No problem really, mostly my own rusty-ness. See KP's response below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking how do you automatically redirect to the given url, instead of having a click needed?

With Javascript, you can simply use the `window.location` property to redirect the browser.

```
window.location = '/somepath/someurl.htm';
```

This will bypass any need for a button click, etc. Just set the location to whatever value is selected in the dropdown.

Comment: Oh, yeah I forgot about that. I'm diving right back into web development and I got so focused on jQuery that I forgot simple javascript can do a lot of the things I need it to. Thanks for the simple and obvious solution!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slimmer version of what I think you're trying to do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang"en">
<head>
    <title>Select Me</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            var cPage = 'Roofing';

            $("#PageSelectDropDown > option[value=" + cPage + "]").attr("selected", "selected");

            $("#PageSelectDropDown").change(function () {
                window.location.href = "/Product/" + $("#PageSelectDropDown option:selected").attr('value');
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

        <select name="PageSelectDropDown" id="PageSelectDropDown"> 
            <option value="Insulation">Insulation</option> 
            <option value="Windows">Windows</option> 
            <option value="Siding">Siding</option> 
            <option value="Roofing">Roofing</option> 
            <option value="Gutters">Gutters &amp; Gutter Protection</option> 
            <option value="PatioDoors">Patio Doors</option>
        </select> 

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for this simplification. Would you mind elaborating how this works a little bit since I am trying to (re)learn jQuery etc?

Comment: The first one I believe says "Change the attribute of the option inside PageSelectDropDown to selected where the value is cPage". The second one seems to be "When I change, change the page location to ... ". I see that this way eliminates the if statement check I had to ignore the current page if it was selected. The event doesn't even fire if you select the same option again, so that if statement was completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.location.replace()`. It will redirect to the page automatically.